# How to login into wordpress.com using HtmlUnit?

Tags: java, wordpress, htmlunit

I want to programmatically login into wordpress.com.

I have already some code used to login into Wordpress standalone instances, but the Wordpress.com login has a different choregraphy.

As far as I understand, when I enter my login, a first request is done returning no secret.

When I enter my login, the submitted form however contains some kind of secret :

```
username=my username
password=my password
remember_me=true
redirect_to=
client_id=a short client id
client_secret=a long client secret which looks like a hash
domain=
```

Where does it come from? And how can I emulate that login choregraphy using HtmlUnit?

Comment: Are those real credentials? If so you may want to remove them, they shouldn't be shared publicly like this for security reasons.

Comment: @cabrerahector obviously not ;-) the only thing I didn't change is the client secret, mainly because, knowing auth schemes, I'm quite sure it'll change soon

Comment: Maybe you can user ChalresWeb Proxy or Fiddler to compare the requests/responses between HtmlUnit and a real browser. Usually this might give you a hint. And if you see something that goes wrong in HtmlUnit please open an issue at github.

Comment: In fact, my current problem is that I don't know how to compute the `client_secret` value, as it is hidden in some heavy JS code ...

Comment: if everything works correct HtmlUnit completely simulates the browser including all the js. If you fill the fields and click the Login button HtmlUnit will login - if not you found a bug.

Comment: In fact, I had to disable JS since it raises weird bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears the wordpress.com website heavily uses Javascript in a way that is absolutly not compatible with lightweightness of HtmlUnit. Seems like I'll have to replace my nice HtmlUnit code with usage of Selenium WebDriver, which I find sooo heavy (but which manipulates real browsers, that the developers of Wordpress.com unfortunatly target).